# Output is a trash value when high precision is required in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I have this code-snippet as part of a bigger program. I've searched the Web for finding a solution for my code and used `long float`, `long double`, `long long int` and also `setprecision(10)`, but no success!

In this code I'm going to put that floating point number (0.000098765) into the `stringstream ss;`(for some purpose) and then put it to output, but when I run the code, a trash value (very very big) will be shown that is clear to be wrong.
It's as bellow:

[image]

How to solve my problem please?

```
int main() 
{
        stringstream ss;
        int temp = 0;
        long double d = 0.000098765;
        long int n = d;
        long double r = d - n;
        ss << n;

           if (d > n)
             {
                if (r < 0.0001)
                  {
                     ss << '.';
                       do {
                             r *= 10;
                             if (r < 1)
                              ss << 0;
                            else
                               {
                                  temp = r;
                                  ss << temp;
                                  r -= temp;
                              }
                       } while (r != 0);
                }
           }
        cout << setprecision(10) << ss.str() << endl;

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `setprecision(10)` doesn't affect the output of a `std::string` value.

Comment: So what else to do please? I need it for a calculator.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that code? If you want to output that number to a `std::stringstream` simply write `ss << setprecision(10) << d;`.

Comment: I need it for calculations in a calculator program (as I said). And OK, if I use your option and not the code I wrote, the output will be a scientific number.

Comment: Use `fixed` additionally.

Comment: A "trash value" is shown because 9.8765 cannot be represented in binary in a finite number of digits. The computer winds up with 9.87650000000000005684341886081 instead. (This is similar to how we cannot represent the fraction 1/3 in decimal in a finite number of digits, but we could easily do so in base 3.)

Comment: What is the *actual* output you're getting? Are the some of the digits correct or not?

Comment: @MarkRansom: Please look at the question again. I posted a screenshot.

Comment: @franky Yup, see my comment. The value you are trying to store in a floating-point variable cannot be accurately represented in floating-point. Beware that floating-point is imprecise. The number 9.8765 represented in binary is 1001.1110**0000011000100100110111010010111100011010100111111011111001110110110010001011010000111001010110000001**... (the bold section repeats indefinitely). As per a previous comment, you should use `std::fixed` instead of a floating-point type if you cannot accept imprecision.

Comment: OK, I probably can use the way offered by the answer below but as I said it's used in a *calculator*. This time the value was that, some time later (depending on the expressions applied by a user) that value may be: **0.0000001**, **-12.36500125**, **168**, **12345.7654121** or whatsoever.

Comment: And for the value **0.2** the output would be **0.2000000000**. It's never accepted.

Comment: @franky 0.2 is also non-terminating in binary (0.001100110011...). I forgot that `std::fixed` only modifies the output format of a stream and is not a number type itself. You should investigate using a fixed-point or high-precision number library.  Floating-point types are not suitable to be used for a calculator application, particularly where your users are not aware of the implications of using floating-point.

Comment: Honestly the reason I wrote that simple code for the issue was that I had experienced many of other alternatives and since hadn't no other choice I had to write that code **that works well** but not for very high precisions.

Comment: @franky If it's just an experiment or a learning exercise then floating point is probably fine. But note that, as I said above, even 0.2 can't be accurately represented in C++'s floating-point types, and that's not exactly an uncommon number to be working with.

Comment: @cdhowie. OK, good. What other alternative? I tested Microsoft built-in calculator and it works well with very very high precissions.

Comment: Read this http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: @n.m. Read it, good info, thanks (+1). How to use Arbitrary-Precision Decimal? It seems to be appropriate for my need.

Comment: You need to find a third party library that implements arbitrary precision decimals, or implement them yourself. Are you doing this out of curiosity or because this is an assignment? The world doesn't need yet another arbitrary precision decimal calculator.

Comment: @cdhowie if you limit your decimal precision to less than that provided by the floating point type, and do rounding after every operation, it's possible to create a decimal calculator that gives the expected results. It's not something to undertake lightly though.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
// ...
long double d = 0.000098765;
// ...
stringstream ss2;
ss2 << setprecision(10) << fixed << d;
cout << ss2.str() << endl;
```

The manipulators operate on the thing fed to the stream, which in your case was a string -- and so 'setprecision' had no effect.

Note also that the 'fixed' manipulator makes the output fixed width, not scientific notation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but please note what I said in the question's body: *...put that floating point number (0.000098765) into the stringstream ss;(for some purpose)...*.

Comment: @howlin Combine that with `std::stringstream` and your answer answers the OP's concern.